# the karaf log doesn't display the date

Tags: apache-karaf

The karaf log doesn't display the date(day month year), it just display the time, is there any configuration should take place to display both the date and the time in karaf log.

Comment: What version are you using? At least the default 2.3.0 release displays the date and the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the configuration for the logging in karaf in the etc folder. The file in question is the org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg. It's a log4j properties configuration style.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a default format like `2019-08-07 15:15:04,349`  , you'll have to edit org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg : by default the date format in the conversion Pattern appears to be `%d{ABSOLUTE}` (HH:mm:ss) : change it to `%d{ISO8601}`.